# C++ - cin.get(array,int) not reading first char

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying some exercises. The first one I wanted to do already got me in trouble. The goal of the exercise is to reverse the string you input. This is easy. But when in try to limit the amount of characters with `cin.get(array,int)` it removes the first character.

**Code:**

```
char voornaam[7];
cin >> voornaam;
cin.get(voornaam,7);

cout << voornaam[6] << voornaam[5] << voornaam[4] << voornaam[3] << voornaam[2] << voornaam[1] << voornaam[0] << endl;
```

This is the code. So this should normally work but when I try it for example with Sander, it outputs 'redna' and then terminates.

Any thoughts on how to fix this. I would like a solution with `cin.get(array,int)` and not with an other function of `cin`.

Thanks.

Comment: *I would like a solution with cin.get(array,int) and not with an other function of cin.* - You already broke that rule with `cin >> voornaam;`.

Comment: Look closely at each line of code and think about what it should do. If you're not sure, look them up at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). Especially the line that @chris mentioned breaking your rules, and the line directly after that.

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of `cin >> voornaam;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is funny. At first instance everything is fine. But with one minor thing. Notice

`cin >> voornaam`

followed by

```
cin.get(voornaam,7)
```

What happens here is, when first prompt comes, you enter Sander.
Hence, `voornaam[0] = 'S'` , `voornaam[1] = 'a'` and so on. And you press enter. `cin.get(voornaam, 7)` takes this as \0. So, your voornaam looks something like

```
voornaam[0] = '\0'
voornaam[1] = 'a'
voornaam[2] = 'n'
```

and so on.

And when you reverse it, you get "redna". So, do not use, cin twice, or enter full string twice to get the correct result.